# JavaScript destroys all children after I append a break?

Tags: javascript, line-breaks, appendchild

I'm creating a script that takes two input dimensions, width, and height, and creates a scaled grid which is representative of how many blocks could fit in a box with the given dimensions with the following function:

```
function makeRow() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= blocksTall; i++) {
            var mb = document.createElement("div");
            mb.setAttribute("class", "matrix-block mb-off");
            mb.setAttribute("onClick", "select_mb('" + j + "," + i + "');");
            placeBlocks.appendChild(mb);
            if (i = blocksWide) {
                placeBlocks.appendChild('br');
            }
        }
    }
```

This function works fine to display the first row of blocks, and then inserts a break tag after the row has finished being rendered, which is exactly what I want to do. The problem is I need to generate 17 more rows, with the same number of blocks, each one under the previous row, so my first thought was, I'll just wrap another for loop around this first for loop and since there is a break there, it will render the new row below the previous one:

```
for (var j = 1; j <= blocksTall; j++) { // Vertical for loop.

    for (var i = 1; i <= blocksWide; i++) { // Horizontal for loop.
        var mb = document.createElement("div");
        //mb.setAttribute("id", "matblock-" + i + "-" + j);
        mb.setAttribute("class", "matrix-block mb-off");
        mb.setAttribute("onClick", "select_mb('" + i + "," + j + "');");
        placeBlocks.appendChild(mb);
    }

    if (j = blocksWide) {
        placeBlocks.appendChild(brk);
    }

}
```

Where `blocksWide` = 17. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyo7fkda/9/) with the complete script. When I log the value for j in the console, it does in fact increment (which tells me that the for loop is working). What seems to be happening though is that it is for some reason rendering the row, and then either rendering the new row on top of it (seems unlikely since the break tag is rendered after each row completes) or, for some reason the children are destroyed each time a new "horizontal" for loop is run.

Does anybody know why this might be happening and how to properly get each row to be appended under the last row so it produces a grid of blocks instead of just one row?

Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is 17 for? Infinity/17  ;o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm a bit confused about some aspects of your script, but I think you have two major issues.

Firstly, you only ever call `document.createElement("br")` once, which means you only ever create a single line-break; and a single line-break can only appear in one place in the DOM. This:

```
        placeBlocks.appendChild(brk);
```

removes `brk` from its current position in the DOM and then puts it at the end of `placeBlocks`. You should change it to this:

```
        placeBlocks.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Secondly, I don't think that `if (j = blocksWide) {` makes sense. Note that it's equivalent to this:

```
j = blocksWide;
if (blocksWide != 0) {
```

which means that it interferes with your for-loop by manipulating the value of `j`. I think the fix for that issue is simply to remove the whole `if`-check, and to perform its body unconditionally.

Comment: j == blocksWide not j = blocksWide, no?

Comment: @SteveHynding: I don't think that `if (j == blocksWide)` makes much more sense than `if (j = blocksWide)` right there. Logically, there should be a line-break at the end of every single row, not just at the end of the row whose index is one greater than the width. No?

Comment: Good point, oversight on my part; no if conditional statement needed is correct +1

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand what you were trying to do with the remainder operators and the dividing, but `blocksWide` resolved to infinity causing an infinite loop, and `blocksHigh` was just 17. All of the other variables besides `full` weren't used.

---

You don't actually need two loops, although it is ok to do that. If you want to use just one loop you basically just need to know if `i` is a multiple of `dispW`.

So you divide `i` by `dispW` then you want to know if it is an integer, to find this you use the remainder operator for `1` and if it resolves to `0` it is an interger. It looks like this...

```
if ((i / dispW) % 1 === 0) 
    // if ( dispW=3 && ( i=3 || i=6 || i=9 || ... ) ) true;
```

This in a loop would look like

```
totalWidth = dispW * dispH; // total number of blocks
for (var i = 1; i <= totalWidth; i++) {
    // do stuff;
    if((i / dispW) % 1 === 0) {
        // insert new line break;
    }
}
```

---

The method you used for selecting the blocks was a round about way of doing it. First you shouldn't use inline javascript, second you shouldn't use javascript to embed inline javascript in a dynamically created element. Use `element.onclick = function;` instead.

Notice there is no braces after the function. This is because you are actually passing the function reference and not the returned value of the function.

`element.onclick` passes an event object to the function reference. You can use this to select the block that was clicked on like so.

```
for ( ... ) {
    ...
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.onclick = myFunction;
    ...
}

function myFunction(e) {
    var clicked = e.target // this is the element that was clicked on
}
```

---

Also, you were creating one `<br>` element outside of the loop. Because `appendChild` moves elements and does not create elements it will just keep moving the line break until the loop finishes. It should look like this.

```
placeBox.appendChild(document.createElement('br')) 
    // append a newly created line break;
```

---

Then even if all the logic worked as intended and you create a new line break every time, floated blocks means no line breaks use `display: inline-block;` instead.

So in the end what you get is...

([Full difference](https://www.diffchecker.com/zhvi4yyb))

```js
window.onload = function () {
    renderGrid();
};
function renderGrid() {
    var blocksTall = document.getElementById('height-in').value;
    var blocksWide = document.getElementById('width-in').value;
    var blocksTotal = blocksWide * blocksTall;
    var placeBlocks = document.getElementById('matrix-shell');
    while (placeBlocks.firstChild) {
        placeBlocks.firstChild.remove();
    }
    console.log(blocksWide + "/" + blocksTall);
    for (var i = 1; i <= blocksTotal; i++) {
        var mb = document.createElement("div");
        mb.className = 'matrix-block mb-off';
        mb.onclick = select_mb;
        placeBlocks.appendChild(mb);
        if (((i / blocksWide) % 1) === 0) {
            var brk = document.createElement("br");
            placeBlocks.appendChild(brk);
        }
    }
}
function select_mb(e) {
    var cur_mb = e.target;
    if (cur_mb.className == "matrix-block mb-off") {
        // Turn cell on.
        cur_mb.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
        cur_mb.className = "matrix-block mb-on";
    } else {
        //Turn cell off.
        cur_mb.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
        cur_mb.className = "matrix-block mb-off";
    }
}
```

```css
.matrix-block {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
}
.mb-off {
    background-color: black;
}
#matrix-shell {
    font-size: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Width:</td>
        <td>
            <input id="width-in" name="width-in" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Height:</td>
        <td>
            <input id="height-in" name="height-in" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <button onClick="renderGrid()">Compute</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<div id="matrix-shell"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful. I appreciate the extra work you did in helping me clean up my script. Some of the things you eliminated where variables I need for future functionality but in the context of this question you are correct and they can be removed with no problem. Just curios about one last thing, namely: What are the advantages to calling the function using the method you suggested vs. using inline js? Is the reasoning for that solely because it was a bunch of sloppy code being generated over and over again, or are there other reasons I should be aware of?